# Erorr 405: When Submitting a Html Form

Tags: php, html, forms, http-status-code-405

I get Error 405 when submitting the HTML form the action is Login.php and the Method is POST Im using Localhost MySQL As the host .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pane">
            <div class="LeftPane">
                <img id="TrafficImage"src="./Images/TrafficJPG.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="RightPane">
                <h2>Sign In</h2>
                <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Full name :" required><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address :" required><br>
                    <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Username :"required><br>
                    <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="email :" required><br>
                    <input type="password" id="Password" name="Passsword" placeholder="Passsword:"  required><br>
                    <input type="password" id="RePassword" name="RePasssword" placeholder="Re-Passsword :" required><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the PHP code where I configure the form details to the database Im saving the form submitted details to the Mysql database named trafiic_light and the table named login.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["Name"];
    $address = $_POST["Address"];
    $username = $_POST["UserName"];
    $email = $_POST["Email"];
    $password = $_POST["Password"];
    $repassword = $_POST["RePassword"];

    if (empty($name) || empty($address) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($repassword)) {
        echo "All fields are required.";
        die();
    }

    if ($password != $repassword) {
        echo "The passwords do not match.";
        die();
    }

    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "trafiic_light";

    // Create a connection to the database
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM login WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    // Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // Bind the results
    $stmt->bind_result($email);

    // Check if the user exists
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($email) {
        echo "The user already exists.";
    } else {
        // Insert the user into the database
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login (name,address,username,email,password,repassword) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $address, $username, $email, $password, $repassword);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "You are successfully registered.";
    }

    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();

    // Close the connection
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: It's interesting that, since the error is in the PHP, you chose not to show us any of the PHP code.

Comment: Sorry for not posting it, Please check it out now Thankyou!

Comment: Have check wheather you have passed correct file path or not in action? And you can try with display data above if  condition so you can get idea wheather request come to that file or not .

Comment: This error is usually what you get, when you try to make a POST request to what the web server thinks is a "static" resource. Are you sure you have your web server set up correctly to actually parse PHP code in `.php` files?

Comment: Nothing in your code will output a 405 error, so it must be something to do with the configuration of whatever HTTP server you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your login.php is in the folder as your index.html (registration page)?
You can try to mention the path specifically like

```
<form action="reg-folder/php/login.php" method="post">
```

Comment: It would take a *really weird* server configuration for an incorrect path, with `.php` on the end of it, to output a 405 error and not a 404 error.

Comment: Maybe sever doesn't allow POST method where the file is being hosted